# c# open pop - save e-mail (HTML with inline attachements) to database

Tags: c#, email, inline, attachment, openpop

Found a problem with saving e-mail to database(as byte[] - already tried with various methods:

**saving "RawMessage", 
executing Message. 
Load via "MemoryStream" etc..), 
retrieving it and re sending.**

When I send this saved e-mail, recipient does not see inline attached image (in place where image should be is information that picture was not found or couldn't be loaded).

My actual code version:

```
byte[] toDB = message.RawMessage; // then it goes to DB
//later in code
OpenPop.Mime.Message raw = new OpenPop.Mime.Message(fromDB, true);
//then I fill in new Message object with new values, only body remains the same:
mailMessage.Body = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(raw.FindFirstHtmlVersion().Body);
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you post the HTML that was sent to the user. Note : Image path in the mail must be referred as link. 
eg: `http://foo.com/images/image.png` and not as `"\images\image.png"`

Comment: Actually, did different way of testing - first I downloaded existing email with attached image inside message via OpenPop and then saved it (byte[] toDB = message.RawMessage). Now I just want to resend it (just HTML body, don't need "real" attachments")